# How to implement protocols and delegates in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was converting one of my swift project into SwiftUI. I need to convert delegtes and protocols to SwiftUI, is it allowed in SwiftUI? or any alternative methods are there? Please help me i'm so confused in SwiftUI.

I'm calling a delegate method from one of my class, then delegate method will be present in another ViewController.

```
//PresenterClass

protocol SplashPresenterDelegate {
    func didFetchedSystemInfo(info: String)
}
class SplashPresenter: NSObject {
    var delegate: SplashPresenterDelegate?

    func getSystemInfo(){
         self.delegate?.didFetchedSystemInfo(info: "ResponseString") 
    }
}


// Viewcontroller class

class myViewController: UIViewController {
   .
   .
   .
}

extension  myViewController: SplashPresenterDelegate{
   func didFetchedSystemInfo(info: String){
      print("delegate called")
   } 
}
```

Please help me to convert this code to SwiftUI

Comment: Protocols are a core part of the swift language and is of course allowed when using SwiftUI. Delegate is a design pattern that also can be used anytime but it is not part of SwiftUI while it was well used in UIKit. Most likely you would want to use a property wrapper here like @State

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have updated my question with code, can you please give a solution?

Comment: The SplashPresenter/Delegate can be used in SwiftUI code as-is. Show your SwiftUI code where you need that presenter.

Comment: @Asperi i want to convert my  MyViewcontroller extension to swiftUI to get delegate from splashpresenter

Comment: You can take closures as parameters in your `ViewRepresentables` to satisfy related delegate methods.

Comment: Think to use an `@Published` in your UIKit class(class extending your Delegate), then you need to use an `@ObservableObject` class with an instance of your UIKit class, now the communication between SwiftUI Views and your Observable Object are more effective. Try to use `.onReceive` method in your views

Answer (score 5):

Typically, SwiftUI prefers the pattern of taking callbacks rather than protocol/delegates. For instance, each button in an `ActionSheet` has a closure that is executed when the button is tapped.

You shouldn't just convert your code over directly, though. SwiftUI, being declarative, uses different paradigms for a lot of things. For instance, you wouldn't have a `didFetchInfo` method, you would just assign it to a @Published variable.

Think about having "**single sources of truth**", where a single variable is always correct. For example, `List` simply takes an array and updates when the array changes, unlike `UITableView` where you provide the data through `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAt`. I don't know enough about your specific project to give more detail, but those are things to think about.